# How to transform cell string value RGB into color number in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I have cells that contain color values ie.:

`RGB(0, 128, 0)`

trying to use this cell.value in VBA to color my cells but my color is not recognized. It shows as string and it does not work

```
"RGB(0, 128, 0)"
```

How to transform this text or remove " " so my color function will work correctly?

```
While Not Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & j).Value = ""
    color = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(j, 2).Value
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(j, 4).Interior.color = color
    j = j + 1
Wend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot interpret strings as code variables/functions.

In other words, you can't expect to write this in a string:

```
str = "a = a + 2"
```

... and expect that your code reads it as:

```
a = a + 2
```

However, what you can do is splitting the three numbers from the string and using them in your code:

```
color = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(j, 2).Value
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(j,4).Interior.Color = RGB(Replace(Split(color,",")(0),"RGB(",""), Split(color,",")(1), Replace(Split(color,",")(2),")","")
```

If you always have the same pattern (like `RGB(0,10,20)` written in a cell), you can think of creating a custom function which returns the three numbers:

```
Private Function splitRGB(ByVal vl As String) As Integer()
    splitRGB = yourArrayWithTheThreeValues '(split as above)
End Function
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can actually evaluate code using `Application.Evaluate` or, for example, `[SUM(5,1)]` - unfortunately, there is no RGB formula, though you may get around that by creating a custom function, though I believe you'd end up having to split it anyway so you're not saving anything unfortunately. What you really want to do is `[RGB(100,100,100)]` which doesn't work unfortunately as RGB is a VBA function. I'm actually playing with this concept atm.

Comment: @matteo  you missing one bracket but it works, thanks `Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(j, 4).Interior.color = RGB(Replace(Split(color, ",")(0), "RGB(", ""), Split(color, ",")(1), Replace(Split(color, ",")(2), ")", ""))`

Comment: @user1274820 unfortunately the method "Evaluate" of the application can't evaluate code variables, but only spreadsheet functions.