# Excel VBA - Set color based on RGB value contained another column

Tags: excel, vba

As part of a larger process I need to create a Excel VBA Macro that read the values from a column and applies basic formatting to the row based on the values in each cell.

The spreadsheet itself is exported from another program and opens directly in Excel.  All columns come across formatted as `General`

The sequence is this:

1. Start at the second row in *Sheet1*
2. Look at *Column J*
3. Read the RGB value (which is shown as `RGB(X,Y,Z)` where *X*, *Y*, and *Z* are the numerical values for the color that needs to be used)
4. Change that rows text Color for *Column A-I* to that color
5. Continue through all rows with text

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778229/how-to-transform-cell-string-value-rgb-into-color-number-in-excel-vba), but I'm not able to make it work.

Any help here much appreciated.

Comment: Is the RGB color written as a string **exactly as you show us**? I mean as "RGB(X,Y,Z)", without any space after comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub ColorIt()
    Set cl = Cells(2, "J")
    Do Until cl = ""
        txt = cl.Value2
        cl.Offset(, -9).Resize(, 9).Font.Color = _
            Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT({" & Mid(txt, 5, Len(txt) - 5) & "},{1,256,65536})")
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

### Edit2

```
Sub ColorIt2()
    Const RGB_COL = "M"
    
    Set cl = Cells(2, RGB_COL)
    Do Until cl = ""
        txt = cl.Value2
        cl.Offset(, 1 - cl.Column).Resize(, cl.Column - 1).Interior.Color = _
            Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT({" & Mid(txt, 5, Len(txt) - 5) & "},{1,256,65536})")
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  I am just now getting to bed but will look at this in the morning.   


The data will ALWAYS be formatted in RGB(X,Y,Z) correctly as it’s being output by another tool and is well formed data.  


So thankfully I don’t have to worry about values that break it.  


I do however need it to loop through each cell with a value in Column J, and I’m fine if the range is (“J:J”) as well.

Comment: I tested this and it works. I had to expand it because I’m starting in *Column M* instead of *Column J*.  Is it possible to adjust this to change the fill color instead?  

I tried using Cell.Interior.Color and it errored out.

Comment: See Edit2 version

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the next function. It will convert the string in a Long color (based on the RGB three parameters. It will work for both caser of comma separators ("," and ", "):

```
Function ExtractRGB(strRGB As String) As Long
   Dim arr: arr = Split(Replace(strRGB, " ", ""), ",")
   ExtractRGB = RGB(CLng(Right(arr(0), Len(arr(0)) - 4)), CLng(arr(1)), CLng(left(arr(2), Len(arr(2)) - 1)))
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub TestExtractRGB()
  Dim x As String, color As Long
  x = "RGB(100,10,255)"
  x = "RGB(100, 10, 255)"
  color = ExtractRGB(x)
  Debug.Print color
  Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A2:I2").Font.color = color
  'or directly:
  Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A2:I2").Font.color = _
      ExtractRGB(Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("J2").value)
End Sub
```

If you comment `x = "RGB(100, 10, 255)"`, it will return the same color valuem for the previous `x` string...

If you need to do it for all existing rows, the code must iterate from 2 to last Row and you only need to change "A2:I2" with `"A" & i & ":I" & i`

If necessary, I can show you how to deal with it, but I think is very simple...

Comment: Wouldn't splitting the strRGB with "," and then trimming be more robust than the above method? What if there would be a 2nd space in there for some reason?

Comment: @Gokhan Aycan what if an "$" will be? Without consistency any code will fail. I considered both cases omly because I suppose that what he shows us may be wrong, not using the normal way of separation in RGB. And yes, trimmung will work, too.